# Best way to optimize ElasticSearch queries with sort clause

Tags: elasticsearch, query-optimization, real-time, bigdata

We have a massive index - with billions of documents - in our 5 node cluster that runs various queries in a parent-child mapping.

When we use the `sort` clause, most of these queries usually time-outs, or keeps forever hangin on this particular huge index.

I was thinking in use some kind of cache, that store the first result, then sort it, or even use some "scalable-jobs-tool" like Apache Spark but will add additional complexity on our infrastructure.

Anyone have some use-case like this can help with some ideas?

**Edit**:

Essentially we have 2 types `user` and `event`, that's the cause we modeling as parent/child - `events` have huge throughput. Usually, we sort by some `custom_data` or other nested-document field, like `revenue`.

That's the mapping of these 2 types:

https://gist.github.com/allansene/5e1e1743b5cbdbd337a19b066fbe8e9b

Below example of query. Without any sort clause, took 51s:

```
    {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "and": {
              "filters": [{
                "has_child": {
                  "type": "event",
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "action": "acessou-pagamento"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }, {
                "not": {
                  "filter": {
                    "has_child": {
                      "type": "action",
                      "filter": {
                        "and": {
                          "filters": [{
                            "term": {
                              "action": "comprou-ingresso"
                            }
                          }, {
                            "range": {
                              "updated_at.date": {
                                "gte": "2016-10-23||/d"
                              }
                            }
                          }]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of sort clause are you using? Can you give some examples?

Comment: @Val i've just added some more informations above...